# Silent renew returning OAuthErrorEvent {type: "silent_refresh_timeout", reason: null, params: null}

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid, access-token

After a call to the connect/authorize endpoint on silent renew it invokes silent_renew.html. but on the log its returning OAuthErrorEvent {type: "silent_refresh_timeout", reason: null, params: null}

I have an angular client.
with silent_renew.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="./" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>silent-renew</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        console.log("Testing" + Date.now());
           parent.postMessage(location.hash, location.origin);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the client setting in identity server is

```
new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = app.ClientId,
                        ClientName = app.ClientName,
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                        RequirePkce = true,
                        RequireClientSecret = false,
                        AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = false,
                        RequireConsent = false,
                        AllowRememberConsent = true,
                        EnableLocalLogin = false,
                        IdentityProviderRestrictions = new List<string> {
                        app.Restrictions
                    },
                        AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
                        RedirectUris =
                    {
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}",
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}/index.html",
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}/callback.html",
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}/silent-renew.html",

                        app.ClientAddress,
                        app.ClientAddress + "/index.html",
                        app.ClientAddress + "/callback.html",
                        app.ClientAddress + "/silent-renew.html"
                    },

                        PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                    {
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}",
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}/index.html",
                        app.ClientAddress,
                        app.ClientAddress + "/index.html"
                    },

                        AllowedCorsOrigins =
                    {
                        $"{configuration["localAddress"]}",

                        app.ClientAddress
                    },

                        AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        app.ClientCode.ToLower()
                    }
                    });
```

I have spent days trying to find the problem, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the log from IdentityServer say?

Comment: @ToreNestenius thanks for reaching out. That's what confused me as well. The identify server returned successfully for the authorize endpoint but after that there was no requests to it and it wasnt a connection problem as well. Anyway I have now updated the silent_renew.html page and its now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs to the same problem here is the solution that worked for me. I was using the wrong setting for silent_renew.html. I replaced it with the following code I got from this link [link](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards) and it worked.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>

      const checks = [
        /[\?|&|#]code=/,
        /[\?|&|#]error=/,
        /[\?|&|#]token=/,
        /[\?|&|#]id_token=/,
      ];

      function isResponse(str) {
        let count = 0;

        if (!str) {
          return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
          if (str.match(checks[i])) return true;
        }

        return false;
      }

      let message = isResponse(location.hash)
        ? location.hash
        : "#" + location.search;

      console.log(
        "Silent refresh iframe is posting to the parent application, message:",
        message
      );

      (window.opener || window.parent).postMessage(message, location.origin);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```